# change text button of the dialog request component

Tags: facebook, text, dialog

Considering the component (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/), I would like know how to change the text of your button. I would like replace the "SEND REQUEST" to just "SEND".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a note: http://developers.facebook.com/policy/ states:

> IV. Application Integration Points
>
> 4 Platform integrations, including social plugins:
>
> ```
>     d. You must not obscure or cover elements of our social plugins,
>       such as the Like button or Like box plugin.
> ```

Which I think applies to that button as well. There is a discussion over the like button here:

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=81844

that probably applies to this question. Other than that, with fbml and fbjs, there was a way to change it, but facebook is deprecating them soon, so it won't even be worth trying using that. I think the only way to go would be to try and get a hold of facebook and make a request to change it, but seeing as how they are always changing things, not sure how that's going to work. If you have an argument as to why, they might listen.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/